# php array reorder values in key

Tags: php, arrays

sometimes I have in array list as 4,5,1,2 and sometimes 1,2,4,5. How could I reorder values in [list] ASC so I will have 1,2,4,5 and 1,2,3 etc in all [list] fields? Thank you.

```
Array
(
    [0] => DibiRow Object
        (
            [storage:ArrayObject:private] => Array
                (
                    [d] => 2012-04-03 08:30:00
                    [list] => 4,5,1,2
                )

        )

    [1] => DibiRow Object
        (
            [storage:ArrayObject:private] => Array
                (
                    [d] => 2012-04-03 09:00:00
                    [list] => 1,2,4,5
                )

        )

    [2] => DibiRow Object
        (
            [storage:ArrayObject:private] => Array
                (
                    [d] => 2012-04-03 09:00:00
                    [list] => 3,1,2                    )

        )
    [3] => DibiRow Object
        (
            [storage:ArrayObject:private] => Array
                (
                    [d] => 2012-04-03 09:00:00
                    [list] => 1,2,3                    )

        )
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Simple matter of `explode()`, `sort()`, and `implode()`.

Comment: great! that was it! I made this:for ($i = 0; $i < count($all) ; $i++) {
  $num = $all[$i][list];
  $resort = explode(",", $num);
  sort($resort);
  $resort = implode(",", $resort); 
  $all[$i][list] = $resort;
}

Answer (score 0):

Try reading something about [bubble sorting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort) first. Then [google](https://www.google.com/search?q=bubble+sort+php) it, find some [examples](http://www.phptutorialonline.com/php-bubble-sort.aspx) and try to do it yourself. If you still have problems, come back and [ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) again, specifying what have you tried and what you think it's wrong with your method.

Answer (score 0):

thank you. I found this solution (don't know if it is effective with large data):

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($all) ; $i++) {
  $num = $all[$i][list];
  $resort = explode(",", $num);
  sort($resort);
  $resort = implode(",", $resort); 
  $all[$i][list] = $resort;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If this is based on the GROUP_CONCAT in results of previous query I wrote you can simply add ORDER BY to the GROUP_CONCAT() -

```
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT user_bookings.user_id ORDER BY user_bookings.user_id)
```